# Is structure behaves as reference type in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I reused class `ClassNationModel` object for one purpose but I recognised object is changing somehow from another module so I created structure `StructNationModel` and declared some variables in it. In another class `Demo` I declared that structure variable and in initialisation of that `Demo` class I assigned the values for parameters of `StructNationModel`  with parameters from `ClassNationModel` but somehow while using  `StructNationModel` object,  I got some updated values from `ClassNationModel`.

How it’s  possible  if I made initialisation  for `StructNationModel` only once and I got updated values for the object of `StructNationModel` even if I not write the code for setting values for it other than initialisation  in `Demo` class

Comment: Some sample code would be helpful to understand your problem.

Comment: Struct is a value type. However, if the struct contains elements that are of reference type, they will still keep the reference semantics. If you introduce any changes to the reference type somewhere else, these changes will also be reflected on this property inside the value type (struct). Do you have a property of reference type inside your struct?

Answer (score 2):

There is no doubt:  a [struct is a value type](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ClassesAndStructures.html#ID88).

If all the members of the struct are also value types, then you have absolutely no issue of uncontrolled changes.  Example:

```
struct S {
    var a : String
    var b : Int
}
var s1 = S(a:"hello", b:12)
var s2 = s1
print ("Two value objects may have the same values: \(s1) and \(s2)")
s1.a="world"
s1.b*=2
print ("But they are different objects. Proof: \(s1) is not \(s2)")
```

However, if some of the struct's members are reference type (e.g. if in your struct, you have a class member),  despite two struct instances will be distinct, they could both refer to the same reference.  Example:

```
class NamedItem : CustomStringConvertible {
    var name : String
    var description: String {
        get { "NamedItem(name:\(name)"}}
    init(name:String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}
struct OUCH {
    var x : NamedItem // The value in OUCH is a reference to another object
    var y : Int
}
var c1 = OUCH(x: NamedItem(name:"Hello"), y:12)
var c2 = c1
print ("Two value objects may have the same values: \(c1) and \(c2)")
c1.x.name="World"  // I don't change c1. x still refers to same object
c1.y*=2
print ("And might share some members of reference type: \(c1) vs \(c2)")
```

Here a visual explanation  of what's happening here:  after the cloning of the struct

[image]

And that's the cause of your issue.